# Mono and Apache are serving files with no ASP.NET processing

Tags: apache, mono, mod-mono, rackspace

On a new Rackspace Cloud Server box (Ubuntu 9.10), I've installed apache2, libapache2-mod-mono, and mod-mono-server2.  I've disabled mod_mono and enabled mod_mono_auto, but whatever I do, requests for Default.aspx return the actual contents of Default.aspx (in this case, "This is a marker file generated by the precompilation tool, and should not be deleted!")

I've installed XSP, and it looks like it works okay, but I'd like to use Apache with mod_mono (seems a more common configuration) if I can get it running.  However, this is no error messages and no hints, with Google obviously not terribly helpful.  What else can I look for to make sure I'm configured correctly?  How can I test further?

Comment: Can you past here your configuration file?

Answer (score 0):

I never did sort out the issue with mod_mono_auto (or `MonoAutoApplication`).  I switched back to mod_mono, set up a mod_mono.conf with the following:

```
MonoAutoApplication disabled
Alias / "/var/www"
AddMonoApplications default "/:/var/www"
<Location / >
SetHandler mono
</Location>
```

...which is all the configuration I needed to do there.  Working as designed for now.